# Change a div content on input change from an URL (WHOIS)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dns, whois

I'm trying to make WHOIS script that can display the availability of a domain name. I already have the PHP done. All I want is the jQuery part that could detect the change of the content of an input, send a POST request to a page and display the content of the page in a certain div.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="input">
    <input type="text" name="domain" placeholder="monsiteweb.com"/>
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

The jQuery I have right now (not working)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=domain]").change(function () { 
        alert("Changed!"); 
});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically:

```
$("input[name=domain]").change(function () { 
    $.post('script.php', { query: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
    });
});
```

then have your PHP script check `$_POST['query']` for the user's input.

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly :)!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing one close brackets there:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=domain]").change(function () { 
        alert("Changed!"); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Also, do not forget that you only get the alert after leaving the field.

Comment: You didn't answer ma question!

Comment: You're right. I saw the error and you pointing out that it did not work, so I simply corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You have opened some brackets, that are not closed:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=domain]").change(function () { 
        alert("Changed!"); 
    });
});
</script>
```